# How do i stop "5.2 GB SWAP partition from appearing in "devices" list in Nautilus?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, swap

I have 12.04 installed and have a 5 GB partition for swap. I want to stop this drive from appearing in the **Devices** list in Nautilus.

```
sanjay@sanjay-pc:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for sanjay: 

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6381b89c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63    83891429    41945683+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda2        83891491   976771071   446439790+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5        83891493   167782859    41945683+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Partition 5 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda6       167782923   503332514   167774796    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Partition 6 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda7       503332578   587223944    41945683+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Partition 7 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda8       587224008   671115374    41945683+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda9       671115438   755006804    41945683+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Partition 9 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda10      755006868   838898234    41945683+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Partition 10 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda11      838898298   922789664    41945683+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Partition 11 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda12      922789728   958437899    17824086   83  Linux
/dev/sda13      958439424   968560639     5060608   83  Linux
/dev/sda14      968562688   976771071     4104192   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: Take a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/156994/partition-does-not-start-on-physical-sector-boundary) , also post the output of `sudo lshw` since it seems your Hard drive is Advanced Format 4096-byte sectors.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the swap partition as only swap and make it a primary partition (not a logical partition). It must be the same size as your RAM, but there is no need to create as large as 5 GB. I am using a 2 GB swap partition and maximum 556 MB of its space ends up being used.

Comment: The swap does not have to be the same size as the amount of physical memory (RAM). It can even be smaller (though if it is smaller, hibernation is not possible).