# 3 TB external, with lots of data, file system not recognized and second partition missing when moved from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have a 3 TB Seagate external drive that I removed and placed in my newly built tower. The 2 TB external I did with this works fine, but the 3 TB drive won't recognize, won't mount, and GParted shows

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbwbw.png) (sorry it's a link - not enough reputation)

After running `fdisk -l` I read in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156994/partition-does-not-start-on-physical-sector-boundary) that it's because it starts on sector 63, but GParted doesn't give me the option to resize this disk.

I'd rather not lose the data on the disk, so I wanted to ask for help before I accidentally deleted everything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Some of the 3TB drives used proprietary or odd work arounds to make drive compatible with XP. XP would not work with correctly partitioned with gpt drives. Fdisk should not even work on a gpt partitioned 3TB drive. It should just show one large gpt partition. But parted or gdisk should then show correct partitions. What does sudo parted -l show?

Comment: Model: ATA ST3000DM001-9YN1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  375GB  375GB  primary               boot

Comment: I have a fresh 4 TB drive installed. Is there a way to copy the data over for recovery and then just wipe the 3 TB drive?

Comment: You are showing MBR(msdos) partitions. So best to convert to gpt. You can copy data and should as backup anyway. But depending on partitions may be able to use gdisk to convert to gpt. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html But just because we now can have multi-TB drives I do not suggest one large partition unless storing video or a few other uses. I also suggest having an efi partition at beginning of drive in case you want to install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. And with the very large drives I suggest an Ubuntu install even if just as an emergency repair boot or backup boot method.