# Ubuntu14.04.1LTS boot error

Tags: 14.04, boot-repair

I desperately need your help. For the past couple of weeks i'm facing serious issues with my laptop, Dell XPS L502X which i bought 3yrs ago. 3 weeks back i installed Ubuntu14.04.1LTS in my laptop by replacing Windows 7. It worked for 1 week or 10days without any issues. But suddenly started giving wierd boot errors.

I followed every forum and tried all the steps but none of them are working to me.  So i was tired of Ubuntu and  tried installing Linux Mint, Xubuntu etc. All of them having same problem. Once booted, it works fine but if boot gives problems like 'attempt to read or write error...' and then one shown in below image thats it nothing works.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz3mj3eoAEUsaW53eVM1SGJIMlh0T2ZzRHBwUVNpbEt2cGVZ/view?usp=sharing

I tried boot-repair n number of times. You won't believe i installed Ubuntu and Ubuntu derivatives nearly 15 to 20 times till now, hoping atleast once it boots up. Installation is getting successful and all problems start while booting.

Now currently i'm back to Ubuntu14.04.1LTS and below is the pastebin URL after running boot-repair:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/9271773/

I ran all HDD and RAM  diagnostics at BIOS level. But all gives PASS as result. I'm not sure what could be the issue. Please please please help me to resolve this issue.

***UPDATE****

I installed Ubuntu12.10 but getting same error while booting up.
Everytime i boot, i see different different errors:

***UPDATE****

I found a discussion related to this partitioning.

[Partition does not start on physical sector boundary?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156994/partition-does-not-start-on-physical-sector-boundary).

I followed the same. Now i don't see any physical boundary related errors for my partitions. Below is latest pastebin URL.

paste.ubuntu.com/9297554/

But still its not booting up. Getting different different errors everytime i boot. Below are some examples.

`Operating System Not Found`

`error: invalid arch independent ELF magic, grub rescue>`

`error: incompatible license`

`error: font characters not ascending order: 22293 <= some number
error: no suitable video mode found.
error: no video mode activated
error: failure writing sector 0x334920 'hd0'.`

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/679725/how-to-correct-512-byte-sector-mbr-on-a-4096-byte-sector-disk 
Your disk is the advanced format type of 512 logical/4096 physical, so you should define all your partitions on multiples of 4096 for aligned boundaries, not 512.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. I'm not OS expert so i want to clarify before doing anything. So you mean to say, i should have partition sizes are multiples of 4096MB. Currently, my boot partition having size 2GB (2048MB), will it be fine if i change it to 4GB(4096MB). Similarly for other partitions.

Comment: The 2048 start in the gdisk output is sectors of 512 bytes apiece, not bytes, so that is certainly a multiple of 4096 and is OK. All the other starts must also be a multiple of 4098 bytes -- use a calculator to check

Comment: Could you please elaborate steps i'm supposed to do. Because the link you provided, talks about GPT partitions but mine is MSDOS partition table. I'm using 'gparted' to partition my HDD. Is there any tool availabe to adjust the start sector of each partition?

Comment: Ok. I found a discussion related to this partitioning.