# Partition problem multi dual systems

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a 1TB disk with primary partition and  one extended partition. With several partitions, some for windows xp , other for linux, and one for truecrypt. In my extenden partition I has 400 gb of non partitioned space. So , i wanted to add a new partition of 120 gb. I tryed to do this using disk management of windows xp ( that was a really bad idea..). When I did that, windows show an error telling me that I should restart disk management. Then it changed all my partition table. Now it doesnt show some of my partitions.
Since this error I havent changed anything in the disk, and I tryed to fix using ubuntu, but I dont know if it can be done, and how. I show you the partition table that shows fdisk.
Any ideas?[here is the fdisk shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwlku.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well thats was a bad idea using disk management of windows xp

What Happed is that Windows disk management has created partitions in the wrong sectors or is ailed them wrong when changing the partitions table. 
I have had this error before and it is fixable you need to re make the partitions to the right sectors you're data should be still there if no formating took place.

The same problem is addressed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156994/partition-does-not-start-on-physical-sector-boundary)

Comment: I wish you the best of luck to fix this.

Comment: Please put some of what that answer says here. It's better practice.

Comment: Thank you Neil, it still doesnt recognize my partition. My lost partition is a truecrypt one. I tryed testdisk and testcrypt but no luck

Comment: your best option is to make a new partition table and a do a Data Recovery here is link on how to do a Data recovery https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery