# How to recovery the data inside my hard drive? New to Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

My computer recognizes my 2tb Green WD on bios but not inside any OS I have installed (I'm running dual boot Windows 10 / Ubuntu 15.10). What I wanna do is make it so Ubuntu let me access it and take my stuff out it, then format is and use it as a shared partition between Ubuntu and Windows. The help I'm asking for right now is how to make Ubuntu show the driver in the files app so that I can retrieve data from it.

Here is the sudo sfdisk -luS command:

As you can see at the end, it knows that the 2tb WD is there, I just don't know why it can't read it, sorry I'm new to this kind of stuff. Any help is appreciated.

Also I'm not sure what this means at the end "Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary."

```
    Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 223,6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000b81c0

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    718847    716800   350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848 307202047 306483200 146,1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       307202048 459546623 152344576  72,7G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       459548670 468860927   9312258   4,5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       459548672 468860927   9312256   4,5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdb: 1,8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x68d28407

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         16126 3515535359 3515519234   1,7T  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb2       3515535360 3907024895  391489536 186,7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Comment: You may want to post the output of `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`

Comment: Here is what I got:
`mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.`

Comment: Try another one: `sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /mnt`. If that doesn't work, try repairing the filesystem with `sudo fsck.vfat -y -v /dev/sdb1`.

Comment: The first command did not work. Here is the output of the second command: 
`fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
Logical sector size is zero.`

Comment: I think it has something to do with this:  [Answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/157000/523054)

Comment: Try this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1908329.

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I finish running a data recovery tool. Thank you from trying to help me, once I have a feedback I will post it here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using the tutorial on [this link](http://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/how-can-i-recover-my-data-from-an-unallocated-hard-disk.html).

Comment: Hi Alexandre, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.