# Container Partition does not start on physical boundary

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I know, question concerning the same problem has already been asked, but I address a different issue.
Following is the output snippet of fdisk.

```
akshayj@akshayj-ThinkPad-T450:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe7ba95a9

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048   3074047   3072000   1.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         3074048 478832639 475758592 226.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       947175424 976771071  29595648  14.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       478834686 947175423 468340738 223.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       478834688 939409407 460574720 219.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       939411456 947175423   7763968   3.7G 82 Linux swap /      Solaris

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

**Main Issue:-**

I know that the solution to the above problem is repartitioning using gparted, but since **/dev/sda4** is just a container partition for **sda5** and **sda6**, shouldn't I just ignore it, or will I face issues and should consider repartitioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typical and most users see this message. You can safely ignore it.

See the answer here [Partition does not start on physical sector boundary?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156994/partition-does-not-start-on-physical-sector-boundary)

Comment: Thanks for the affirmation, I had already seen that link.