# Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, fdisk

I Installed Ubuntu erasing Windows couple of days ago. Now Ubuntu is using the entire HDD.

When I run fdisk -l result shows something like:

```
.........
Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors`
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa1767c2b

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 960894975 960892928 458.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       960897022 976771071  15874050   7.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       960897024 976771071  15874048   7.6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris`

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Does this Extended partition bad for performance or HDD?
And How can I fix it?
I read some article but I don't understand what really need to do. If possible please give me some suggestion like on some article I've seen something like that 'Use Gparted to move 512to 4k....' type suggestion. I tried using gparted, I can do anything. There are only two options 'Manage flags and Information'

I use Lenovo ThinkPad.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

`sda2` is the  extended partition which holds the logical partition `sda5`.
You never read from or write to `sda2`, you read from or write to `sda5` and `sda5` appears perfectly aligned. So there won't be any negative effect for your disc-performance, leave it as it is.