# make NTFS partion in a fully ex4 formatted hardisk

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, ext4

I have a fully ex4 formated hard disk. I shrinked 130 GB of My Hard disk space and now This 130 GB is free space. This is partion table:

[image]

When I want to Format this free space to NTFS with `disks` software. But I get this error:

> Error creating partition on /dev/sda: Command-line `parted --align
>   optimal --script "/dev/sda" "mkpart logical ext2 544923MiB
>   700242198527b"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Error: You
>   requested a partition from 571GB to 700GB (sectors
>   1116002304..1367660543). The closest location we can manage is 571GB to 700GB (sectors 1116002304..1367660542).  (udisks-error-quark, 0)

I tested with `Gparted` But same error appears agian. 
Any Idea why this happnes?

Comment: Logical partitions must have one sector between them. And newer 4K drives need to be on boundaries to improve performance.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/156994/partition-does-not-start-on-physical-sector-boundary But why do you want a NTFS logical partition. Windows only installs to primary partitions. And while Linux can read/write NTFS, it cannot maintain it. You need Windows or Windows repair disk to run chkdsk & defrag which may regularly be required.

Comment: @oldfred Thanks. I wanted to install windows Os alongside my xubunu. :)) So I decided to shrink about 100GB as NTFS.

Comment: Windows only installs in BIOS mode to primary NTFS partition with boot flag. So it must be sda1 thru sda4. You have used sda1 & sda2 as extended. so you need to move partitions around so unallocated is not in the extended so you can make it sda3. Make sure you have good backups. Does sda1 need to be 461GB? Easier shrinking it as then unallocated will automatically be outside extended. Otherwise moving partitions and shrinking extended from front required.